# Cross references, bibliographic references, and the "referencing" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

At the moment, the tagging approach regarding "references" (in the broadest sense) seems to be as follows:

- Questions about cross references (dealing with `\label`, `\ref` & friends) will consistently be tagged as `referencing`.
- Questions about bibliographic references (dealing with `\bibliography`, `\cite` & friends) will normally be tagged as `bibliographies`.
- A minority of questions about bibliographic references features the `referencing` tag instead.
- Only rarely does a question feature both the `referencing` and the `bibliographies` tag (and then sometimes only because of retagging by a high-reputation user).

In my opinion, the current situation is undesirable because the `referencing` tag may stand for two related, but distinct topics (cross references vs. bibliographic references). I suggest the following change (with two variants):

1. Questions about bibliographic references currently featuring the `referencing` tag should be retagged to `bibliographies`. (The questions concerned will have to be sorted out by hand.)
2. Like 1, but in addition the `referencing` tag should be renamed to `cross-referencing` (with `referencing` as a tag synomym).

EDIT: As no one objected and Stefan has already started retagging, I'll consider my proposal as accepted. For now, I suggest that any question about bibliographic references that features "special tags" like `biblatex` or `natbib` doesn't need a `bibliographies` tag (just as questions tagged with `tikz-pgf` don't feature the `graphics` tag). IMO, `bibtex` should also be regarded as a "special tag", e.g. for questions regarding the `bib`-format or programming questions.

Retagging some of the `(cross-)referencing` questions to `bibliographies` will flood the start page to a certain extent, but I don't see how this can be avoided.

EDIT2: The `cross-referencing` tag needed to be removed from nine questions.

Comment: While we are at it: why are there 78 [tag:bibtex] questions, but only 56 [tag:bibliographies] questions?

Comment: @Caramdir: Good question. ;-) Seriously, once we have sorted out questions about cross-references, the tagging of the "bibliographic references" subject area could use further refinement, but I haven't made up my mind about it (yet).

Comment: While renaming and merging tags doesn't affect the front page, retagging a single question does. So perhaps let's modify concerned questions not all at once but distributed over some time.

Comment: @Stefan: Removing the `cross-referencing` tag from nine questions all at once was acceptable IMO. Anything regarding the `bibtex` tag should be done over some time - except that I'll retag new `bibtex` questions to `bibliographies` in cases of doubt.

Comment: @lockstep: bibliographies tag wiki is created. I hope this helps to clarify further in using those tags.

Comment: @Stefan: Looks good! Three suggestions: 1. I would not mention `tocbibind` because it is a package to include bibliographies, indexes etc. in the ToC, not to manage bibliographies. 2. Because of biblatex, the fourth sentence should read "In standard LaTeX, the command `\bibliographystyle` is used ..." 3. The comment about BibTeX should read "If your question is specifically about BibTeX (e.g. how to modify a bst-file), use the `bibtex` tag."

Comment: @Stefan: I have incorporated suggestions no. 1 (tocbibind) and no. 3 (BibTeX) into the tag wiki. Suggestion no. 2 ("In standard LateX[...]") seemed to esoteric for an introduction on second thought.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that bibliography questions should not have a `referencing` tag. I think that restricting that tag to cross-referencing only (`\label`, `\ref` and variants) would be ok. Renaming the tag to `cross-referencing` would support that. The already existing `cite` tag (hm, I would like to rename that to `citing`) covers bibliographic referencing well enough.

Btw. I worried more about seeing reference book questions tagged this way, but fortunately I can see that such questions are well tagged with `documentation`, `manual` or `books` though sometimes carrying "reference" in the title.

**Update:**

As agreed, I changed `referencing` into `cross-referencing` since I'm sure this term is the better naming. You may compare [Cross-reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-reference) vs. [References](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/References) in the Wikipedia.

Additionally, I've written a [cross-referencing wiki entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-referencing/info) which explains the tag, mentions the standard commands `\label` and `\ref` and further related packages with links, noting that questions about citing or bibliographies belong to the bibliographies tag.

**Update 2:** I created the [bibliography tag wiki](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/bibliographies/info).

Comment: @Stefan: The `cite` tag should be also okay for bibliographic references, but `bibliographies` has far more questions tagged with it (and  I don't see the need for two different tags). Perhaps we (e.g. Andrew Stacey ;-)) could create a `bibliographies-citing` tag?

Comment: @lockstep: Stefan has all the same powers as I do!  @both: I see nothing wrong in this plan.  Wherever there's ambiguity, it's good to rename tags to remove it and make it so that a user who _doesn't_ know about the tags will easily select the right one when it gets suggested.

Comment: @lockstep: If I've got a question to tag, I would choose `citing` for problems with `\cite`, `\footcite`, compression of references and the like, but for layout and generation of bibliographies the `bibliographies` tag. Such info could go into the tag wikis.

Comment: @Stefan: Sometimes a distinction between `citing` and `bibliographies` may be warranted, but in practice many bibliography adjustments (e.g. author-year instead of numeric style) will also affect in-text-citations and vice versa. (Perhaps it's a bit like trying to differentiate between tikz- and pgf-related questions.)

Comment: Sometimes it would be useful to have a tag hierarchy (such that every `citing` question is automatically a `bibliographies` question, but not the other way round). In the absence of that, I think the 18 `cite` and 2 `citations` questions can be merged into `bibliographies`. Most of these questions are already tagged `bibliographies` or `bibtex`.

Comment: Also, `cite` is a package so that tag could be reserved for questions about it. (Although it's a less widely used package nowadays with natbib and biblatex around.)

Comment: @Will: The problem with using `cite` for a package is that it is ambiguous so a new user won't know that it is especially for that package.  Where package names are also ordinary words, they should have an obvious package suffix, like `cite-package`.

Comment: Now it's called `cross-referencing` together with a tag wiki entry, see my update notice above.

Comment: Thank you. Small typo: “about these ore related commands” (I can't edit the tag wiki).

Comment: @Caramdir: thanks, I corrected it.

Comment: @Stefan: The tag wiki looks good.  Is it meant to be the case that any question about source citations should get one of the [tag:bibliographies], [tag:bibtex], or [tag:biblatex] tags, but need not get more than one?

Comment: @Charles: good question! I left that open... but I think the specific `bibtex` or `biblatex` tag would be sufficient. `bibliographies` could mark more general bibliography question independent of the database tools - at least there's the "Related tags" list on the right which has its purpose. But a second or third tag probably doesn't hurt ... it's a general question regarding broader vs. specific tags.

Comment: @Charles: I think so (and see Caramdir's comment about tag hierarchies). A fourth tag that is frequently used is `natbib`.

Comment: @Stefan: I retagged two question from `cite` to `cite-package`. Now, the `cite` and `citations` tags could be defined as aliases for `bibliographies`.

Comment: I did cursory skims of the 80 or so questions tagged with `bibtex` and only found two where the `bibliographies` tag seemed more appropriate.

Comment: Hm, after doing this we could never distinguish questions regarding specifically the `\cite` command (and related) from the broad topic `bibliographies`. Though separating package from command(s) is fine. I tend to keep a tag `citing` specifically for all citing commands within the body text.

Comment: @Stefan: I think this question can be tagged with {status-completed}.