# Making {cite} and {citations} a synonym of {citing}

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

This is basically a reanimation of a retagging proposal of @Stefan Kottwitz in the last comment to [this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/755/cross-references-bibliographic-references-and-the-referencing-tag/756#756) answer (also from Stefan): Merge [cite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cite) and [citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations) into a new [citing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citing) tag. And yes, this would involve no manual retagging. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I merged those closely related tags into [citing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citing). Now there are 35 questions about [citing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citing). I added that concept tag also to the two existing [cite-package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cite-package) questions.